# TabLayout в фрагменте не показывает содержимое ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Использую TabLayout внутри фрагмента:

Разметка фрагмента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/accent"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="center" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Внутри фрагмента onCreateView:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_home, container, false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    TabsPagerFragmentAdapter adapter = new TabsPagerFragmentAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(HomeUserInfoFragment1.getInstance(), "1");
    adapter.addFrag(HomeUserInfoFragment2.getInstance(), "2");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Адаптер FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public class TabsPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public TabsPagerFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

public void addFrag(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}
}
```

Что в итоге получаем:
Первый скрин Android 4.1.1
Второй Android 5.1

[image: В версии API 16 (4.1.1)]
[image: В версии API 22 (5.1)]
Сами фрагменты не отрисовываются, перелистывание работает, но содержимого нет.

Так же в версии 6.0 содержимое табов есть только благодара "костылю"

```
tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
});
```

UPD:
Контейнер куда вставляется фрагмент с табами:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar_default"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_login_window" />
```

Вставляю  в ScrollView, может в этом проблема?! Только сейчас об этом вспомнил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Помогло:**

Родительский контейнер фрагмента был `ScrollView`. Замена его на `LinearLayout` решила проблему.

---

Попробуйте вместо

> android:layout_width="wrap_content"

для `TabLayout` проставить

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

**UPD_0:**

Попробуйте не передавать в адаптер фрагменты, а создавать их сразу в `getItem(int position)` методе адаптера по позиции:

```
getItem(int position)
{
    switch(position)
    {
        case 0:
        return HomeUserInfoFragment1.getInstance();
        default:
        return HomeUserInfoFragment1.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Уже пробовал, результата нет. :(

Comment: То что они такие маленькие, бог с ними, это правится - app:tabGravity="fill", вопрос в том, что фрагменты не подгружаются.

Comment: Если создавать фрагменты на ходу, то эффект точно такой же.

Comment: Может у вас с шириной контейнера для фрагмента беда? Покажите разметку активити, в коей контейнер для фрагмента.

Comment: Да, проблема именно в том, что родительский контейнер для всего этого был ScrollView!

Comment: Т.е. вы убрали `ScrollView` и всё заработало?..

Comment: Да, я заменил ScrollView на LinearLayout и все заработало.